# Cannot login to oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I cannot log into oracle SQL developer. I am receiving an error which says that the listener refused the connection (ORA 12505).

I am using the Oracle 10 express edition. The server and the sql developer are on the same machine, and I am using windows 8. I used to access the system all the time, but I have not used my computer for a month. I have looked through all the related questions, and I have not found anything helpful. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you connect with `sqlplus`?

Comment: Is the server software running?

Answer (score 1):

You really should put more information to understand better you current scenario and configuration.

This is caused because the listener receives a petition to establish a connection with the db. The connection descriptor receives in that listener a SID for an instance that has not been registered yet (statically or dynamically).

You could do the following:

- Check which instance are currently known by the listener by executing: lsnrctl services
- Check that the SID parameter in the connection descriptor specifies a known instance.
- You could check the event log in listener.log

As I said before, it's difficult to help you without further information. Also, there are tons of information for ORA errors in the web, without needing to put that question here.

You could check the official oracle documentation, or just Ask Tom....